# fail2ban: if a line matches both failregex and ignoreregex, which one has priority?

Tags: firewall, fail2ban

What the subject says. I have an user who logs in using SSH through a provider that gives him a dynamic IP from a pool; all of their IPs map to `static.hostingprovider.name`, but that name doesn't resolve back to the same IP address.

SSH detects this and spits out the message "POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT", which triggers the failregex. I want to add an exception so that, if the connection attempt comes from `static.hostingprovider.name`, it ignores the warning. If I just add `static.hostingprovider.name` to the ignoreregex list, will it simply work?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `jail.local` file add this line:

`ignoreip = static.hostingprovider.name`

Comment: Does that work with DNS names too? Not just with IPs?

Comment: Yes, it does. But keep in mind that this will also protect any attacker from the same ISP.